# How Can I solved this Cypress Test Runner Error?

Tags: cypress

When I run the command `npm run cypress` my test runner is opening and I am able to run all of the test scripts.
But I get one error after open the runner.

```
[12836:1125/143940.980:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(125)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
```

[image]

Comment: An error alone won't make it possible for us to help you. Try to show us a more re-producible example including the code that causes the error

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Just installed Cypress on Windows for my project (npm install).  However, running npx cypress open, shows the same error

Comment: did anyone resolved this?